# Issue with if statement in tradingview pine script

Tags: pine-script

i try to put in a simplified switch-statement in my tradingview pine script:

```
//@version=3
study("my_test",shorttitle="bands",overlay=true)

string VOLA_INDEX = ""

if (ticker == "USOIL")
   VOLA_INDEX := "OVX"
if (ticker == "GOLD")
   VOLA_INDEX := "GVZ"
if (ticker == "GER30")
   VOLA_INDEX := "DV1X"   


src = security(ticker,"D",close[1])
vola = security(VOLA_INDEX,"D",close[1])

bands1 = src * vola/100 * sqrt(0.00273972602) 
bands3 = src * vola/100 * sqrt(0.00821917808) 

upper1 = src + bands1
lower1 = src - bands1

plot( src, title="mean", color=black, style=linebr, linewidth=2, transp=100, trackprice = true,offset=-9999)
plot( upper1, title="upper", color=blue, style=linebr, linewidth=2, transp=40, trackprice = true,offset=-9999)
plot( lower1, title="lower", color=blue, style=linebr, linewidth=2, transp=40, trackprice = true,offset=-9999)
```

somehow, this could fails.

Someone an idea whats wrong with the syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you add the error / output you are getting to help people answer your question?

Comment: You should use the `:=` operator when you want to reassign values.

Comment: using the := operator i got

line 8: mismatched input 'vola' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: @HeinrichBerger could you provide minimal reproducible code snippet?  None of us knows where `line 8` in your code, what `vola` is etc.

Comment: i added the full code and removed the duplicated line

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate VOLA_INDEX before assigning a value to it.

string VOLA_INDEX = ""

Comment: i have tried and updated the code above. for this , i got the return: syntax error at input 'VOLA_INDEX'

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as you want, because `security` can't take mutable param (which is the `VOLA_INDEX` string). I fixed your code via `?`-operator so the code shows how you can implement your idea. By the way, I've translated the code to pine v.4 and my advice here is to use v.4, because previous versions aren't supported so there could be some problems.

```
//@version=4
study("my_test",shorttitle="bands",overlay=true)


vola = syminfo.ticker == "USOIL" ? security("OVX", "D", close[1]) :
  syminfo.ticker == "GOLD" ? security("GVZ", "D", close[1]) :
  syminfo.ticker == "GER30" ? security("DV1X", "D", close[1]) :
  na // I'm not sure about this. What should be here if none of the symbols matches

src = security(syminfo.ticker, "D", close[1])


bands1 = src * vola/100 * sqrt(0.00273972602) 
bands3 = src * vola/100 * sqrt(0.00821917808) 

upper1 = src + bands1
lower1 = src - bands1

plot(src, title="mean", color=color.black, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, transp=100, trackprice = true,offset=-9999)
plot(upper1, title="upper", color=color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, transp=40, trackprice = true,offset=-9999)
plot(lower1, title="lower", color=color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, transp=40, trackprice = true,offset=-9999)
```

Comment: Hello. Many thanks and i have got your point. I will add the missing part with your na which you are right about but i have cut the code to the most relevant parts. Many many thanks!!!